# My WordPress Website Show a line of code on the top

Tags: php, wordpress

When I change my theme the new theme shows a line of code on the top of the all pages of website. This code has ini_set() functions. The shown code is given below.

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' ); @ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M'); @ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
```

How can i remove this code ? I have checked header.php but did not find any thing. Please help.

Comment: Why would you want to remove this line?

Comment: it displayed on the top of website above header. Visible to everyone

Comment: Be sure this code is wrapped in `<?php` `?>` then. Also, if you use SublimeText, you can search for strings into a whole directory. Use this feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are viewing is code that is outside of php tags so the server interprets it as plain text and displays it, as it should.

You would need to find the offending page and remove the code. There are a lot of pages in a wordpress install. If you are unsure how to proceed you need to  contact the theme developer in an ideal situation and report the bug and ask them where to change it at.

Alternatively you could try and grep if you have jailshell or ssh access

```
grep -ir ini_set *
```

Sometimes a theme will include things in the themes `functions.php` file so I would check there. There is no overall simple solution on this one. You just have to find the text in your files manually or automatically using grep or another program (like notepad++) and either add php tags around it, or remove it. Good luck!

One thing to consider is, if the theme developer left this most simplest problem in the theme, do you really want to expose your wordpress to the security holes and bugs that more complicate code could have? You should not even use this theme anymore at this point as you are just risking compromise.

Comment: thanks dear @Runthis